# Syntax Error near Unexpected Token in a bash function definition

Tags: bash, shell, function

Forgive me; I'm pretty new to bash files and the like.  Here is a copy of my .bashrc:

```
alias k='kate 2>/dev/null 1>&2 & disown'

function kk {kate 2>/dev/null 1>&2 & disown}
```

The alias in the first line works fine, but the second line throws:

```
bash: /home/mozershmozer/.bashrc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `{kate'
bash: /home/mozershmozer/.bashrc: line 3: `function kk {kate 2>/dev/null >1>&2 & disown}'
```

I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 and those are the only two lines in my .bashrc file.  Pretty much everything else on my machine is default vanilla.  Ultimately I want to play around with the function to get it to do some specific things, but I hit the syntax wall immediately.  The exact function I have listed here is just a sort of experimental dummy to allow me to learn the syntax more clearly.

Comment: @Fox Holy crap I can't believe I never realized the spaces were in all the examples.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `bash` and other POSIX shells, `{` and `}` aren't exactly special *symbols* so much as they are special *words* in this context.  When creating a compound command like in your function definition, it is important that they remain *words*, i.e. surrounded by whitespace.

The final command in a single-line function definition like this must be terminated by a semicolon. Otherwise the closing brace `}` is treated as an argument to the command.

---

As an aside, **if** you want your function to be portable to other POSIX shells, it is better to use a different function syntax:

```
kk () { kate 2>/dev/null 1>&2 & disown; }
```

The use of `function` is specific to `bash`, while the form given here works with `bash` as well as others like sh, Korn and Almquist shells.

`disown` is also bash specific.

Comment: `disown` is also `bash`-specific, but the POSIX-compatible function syntax is preferred when possible.

Comment: I do not get the 2nd bit in your comment. Is there a posix-compatible syntax for disown? what is it? Could you put the info from your comment in your answer.

Comment: @richard Oh, thanks for the edit. `nohup` is sort of but not really a POSIX-compatible `disown`, but it works differently and is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: FWIW, `function` is also in `ksh93` (it may have started there; I'm not sure).  `ksh88` only had the `f()` form.  In `ksh` there are differences between `function f` and `f()` definitions (eg `typeset` scoping for local variables).

Comment: Correction, ksh88 also had `function f` format, but the meaning changed for `f()` between ksh88 and ksh93 to become POSIX compliant.  See Q18 of http://kornshell.com/doc/faq.html

Comment: @StephenHarris, actually ksh's `function f { ...; }` predates the `f() cmd` SysV sh syntax (long before ksh88, IIRC it's 1981 vs 1982 though ksh wasn't released outside of AT&T before 1983)

Comment: `disown` is not bash-specific. It comes from `zsh` (1.0 1990), added much later to bash (2.0, 1996)

Answer (score 2):

Putting it on to multiple lines avoids having to put in the extra `;`, and gives one way to write a function, even when it contains lots of commands.

```
function kk {
    kate 2>/dev/null 1>&2 & disown
}
```