# Run two commands one after another in bash, via a function, called with `eval`

Tags: bash, command-line, random

I am facing problems running two commands one after another in bash. 
When I run

```
source2() { '/home/ds/Documents/scripts/Untitled Document 1.sh' && imgpath="$(ls | grep "^unsplash")" }

source3()  {  '/home/ds/Documents/scripts/Untitled Document 2.sh' && imgpath="$(ls | grep "^1920x1080" | shuf -n 1)" }

source4()   {  '/home/ds/Documents/scripts/Untitled Document 3.sh' && imgpath="$(ls | grep "^unsplashimg")" }



SOURCES=("source2" "source3" "source4")
$(eval $(shuf -n1 -e "${SOURCES[@]}"))
echo $imgpath
```

The bash script part runs, but the part after `&&` does not
and hence `echo $imgpath` gives no output. When I run individual commands like

```
'/home/ds/Documents/scripts/Untitled Document 1.sh' && imgpath="$(ls | grep "^unsplash")"
```

then I get desired outputs.

What am I doing wrong?

I have taken hints from

- [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)
- [How can I store commands as variables and execute them randomly in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568926/how-can-i-store-commands-as-a-variables-and-execute-them-randomly-in-bash)

Comment: Are you sure your function definitions are even syntactically correct? see for example [Syntax Error near Unexpected Token in a bash function definition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296362/65304)

Comment: Refer to Jetchisel answer here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/568926/314322 ; I just replaced the convert command with bash script

Comment: You also apparently compressed the function body to a single line as well - in that case, the final command must be terminated with a `;` to allow correct parsing of the following `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax issues aside, it's how you're calling `eval`:

```bsh
$(eval $(shuf -n1 -e "${SOURCES[@]}"))
```

The outer `$(...)` mean that the eval happens inside a subshell, then the current shell takes the **output** and executes *that* as a command.

Because eval runs in a subshell, the contents of the variable will disappear with the subshell.

Now, do you need `eval`? The `shuf` command will produce a string with the same name as a function. You could write instead:

```bsh
func=$(shuf -n1 -e "${SOURCES[@]}") && "$func"
```

or simply

```bsh
$(shuf -n1 -e "${SOURCES[@]}")
```

In the last case, we *do* want the shell to execute the output of shuf as a command